# Incorrect Cookie Value While Reading In PHP

Tags: php, cookies

I'm setting a cookie to stop certain things loading up on my page if I'm an admin user, and to do this I'm creating a cookie in php, reading it, and then echoing out the value via php on my page.

So my full code snippets are:

```
<?php
setcookie("preview", "true", time() - 3600); // Kills Existing
setcookie("preview", "true", time() + 3600); // Sets New
?>
```

-

```
<?php
if(isset($_COOKIE["preview"])){
$admin_preview = ($_COOKIE["preview"]);
}
else{
$admin_preview = "false";
}
?>
```

-

```
<?php
echo $admin_preview;
?>
```

So when I echo out `$admin_preview`, I'm expecting `true` to be the value, but instead I'm getting `1`.

I'm using `Firefox 62.0` so I can't view the actual cookie value, but I've obviously done something wrong. Any ideas where or how?

Comment: 1 = true; 0 = false

Comment: @D.Dimitrov So you're saying that setting `true` is making it `1`? Shouldn't it echo out `true` as a word rather than a numeric value?

Comment: This `$admin_preview = "false";` is setting to the string literal "false", not the boolean `false`

Comment: @DinoCoderSaurus I've changed `true / false` to `yes / no`, but I'm still getting shown a `1`?

Comment: @W.H. I tried your code, i'm getting "true" response. Maybe something is wrong on your side. Can you post exactly code?

Comment: @D.Dimitrov the code works over 3 different scripts, so I can't post it in full. I set the cookie in my admin files and read it in the website pages. Not sure why it's even setting a numeric `1`

Answer (score 2):

Do this instead :

```
$admin_preview = var_export($_COOKIE["preview"], true);
```

This will state that the value of the "preview" cookie is to be used as a string instead of a boolean.
In php boolean words (true/false) translate to 1 and 0 in that order, you have to explicitly state that the value is to be used as a string if that's what you wish for.

Comment: Thanks. That's all well and good, but I've changed it to `Yes/No` and I'm still seeing the same `1` as the value. I've tried removing the cookies from the browser, but when I run the script again I see 4 cookies set. I can't see what they are but surely only one should be one set?

Comment: Try a different browser? a 'yes' should never be translated to a 1 so I'm assuming that some old cookies are still causing havoc.

Comment: Thanks. I've removed the cookies again (this time noticing the `save` button). I re-ran the script and it's now working correctly.

Comment: Brilliant, if you could please accept the answer it would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

In PHP 1 means true, you can check it like if($admin_preview) //which will accept it as true,

also you can use filter var.

```
var_Dump(filter_var("TRUE", FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN));
//or
var_Dump(filter_var(1, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN));
```

for more information about boolean in php you can check http://php.net/manual/tr/language.types.boolean.php

also you are not doing it wrong dude.